# Insertion in map using array - error: cannot bind rvalue reference of type ‘int&&’ to lvalue of type ‘int’

Tags: c++, arrays, unordered-map, std, std-pair

I want to insert values of two arrays : `A` and `T` in an `std::unordered_map` (named `unordered`) by following code:

```cpp
for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
{   
    unordered.insert(std::make_pair<int, int>(A[i], T[i]));
}
```

I am getting the following error:

> error: cannot bind rvalue reference of type ‘int&&’ to lvalue of type ‘int’

I guess it is because the `operator[]`  returns a reference to a variable, but then how to do it otherwise?

This is the rest of my code:

```cpp
int N;
cin >> N;

int A[N], T[N];

std::unordered_map<int, int> unordered;

for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
{
    cin >> A[i];
}
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
{
    cin >> T[i];
}
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
{
    unordered.insert(std::make_pair<int, int>(A[i], T[i]));
}
```

Comment: Can we get a [mre]?

Comment: instead of using ```std::make_pair``` you can say ```unordered.insert({A[i], T[i]});``` using curly braces ```{}```

Comment: TL;DR of the dupe: `unordered.insert(std::make_pair<int, int>(A[i], T[i]));` should be `unordered.insert(std::make_pair(A[i], T[i]));`.  Let the compiler figure out the type for you.  If you don't, the function changes from taking a forwarding reference to an rvalue one, which gives you this error.

Comment: On a side note: `int N; cin >> N; int A[N], T[N];` - [variable-length arrays are non-standard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/).  Use `std::vector` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to do it otherwise?

You are explicitly providing the template parameters of `std::make_pair` to make the compiler to forcefully choose the following [`std::make_pair`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/make_pair)'s overload

```
template< class T1, class T2 >
std::pair<V1,V2> make_pair( T1&& t, T2&& u );
```

This is not required, let the compiler do the deduction

```
unordered.insert(std::make_pair(A[i], T[i]));
```

or

```
unordered.insert({A[i], T[i]});
```

or using [`std::unordered_map::emplace`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/emplace)

```
unordered.emplace(A[i], T[i]);
```

---

Note that the `A` and `T` are variable length arrays, which are not part of standard c++. More read: [Why aren't variable-length arrays part of the C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard)
Use `std::vector` instead of the VLAs.

That being said, do you really need to store the user input in between to an array! You could also directly insert the key-values to the map on the go as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

int main() 
{
    int N; std::cin >> N;

    std::unordered_map<int, int> unordered;

    for (auto i = 0u; i < N; ++i)
    {
        int key{}, value{};
        std::cin >> key >> value;      // get the user input (key and value)
        unordered.emplace(key, value); // like this
        // or
        // unordered.insert(std::make_pair(key, value));
        // or
        // unordered.insert({ key, value });        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Coceptually you can use `std::move` as shown below.

```
unordered.insert(std::make_pair<int, int>(std::move(A[i]),std::move( T[i])));
```